# How to write Linq depending if a value is provided or not

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to write a LINQ statement with some optional where clauses. This is for a search. The user can select a specific site to search or search against all sites:

```
var query =
    _db.STEWARDSHIP
       .OrderBy(r => r.SITE.SITE_NAME)
       .Where(r => r.SITE_ID == SiteId)
       .Where(r => r.VISIT_TYPE_VAL.VISIT_TYPE_ID == VisitTypeId)
       .Select(r => new
       {
           id = r.STEWARDSHIP_ID,
           name = r.SITE.SITE_NAME,
           visit_type = r.VISIT_TYPE_VAL.VISIT_TYPE_DESC,
           visit_date = r.VISIT_DATE
       });
return query;
```

So when the method gets SiteId = 14, for instance, no problem. However, when it gets SiteId = null, then that where clause should not be considered.

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just edit the where clause to something like

```
 .Where(r=>SiteId == null || r.SiteId == SiteId)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible since there are no records where the SITE_ID is null. So, this would never return a result.

Comment: @Eric:  This doesn't check SITE_ID for null; it checks the given `SiteID` value for null.

Comment: @AustinSalonen, so if it is null, the WHERE clause would be ignored?

Comment: @Eric:  If it's null the where clause would be `.Where(r => true)` so it would filter nothing.

Answer (score 5):

That's easy:

```
var query = _db.STEWARDSHIP.OrderBy(r => r.SITE.SITE_NAME);

if (SiteId != null)
{
    query = query.Where(r => r.SITE_ID == SiteId);
}
query = query.Where(r => r.SITE.SITE_TYPE_VAL.SITE_TYPE_ID == SiteTypeId)
             .Select(r => new
              {
                  id = r.STEWARDSHIP_ID,
                  name = r.SITE.SITE_NAME,
                  visit_type = r.VISIT_TYPE_VAL.VISIT_TYPE_DESC,
                  visit_date = r.VISIT_DATE
              });
return query;
```

This works because queries *compose* nicely - and they really only represent queries; it's only when you try to fetch data from them that the query is actually executed.

Comment: They don't compose so nicely with the scenario of OR compositions (unless you make an extension method to edit the expression tree).

Comment: @JeffN825: Well, you can use `PredicateBuilder` for that - but in this case that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm stealing a trick from TSQL.  Just check for the null value as well.

```
...
.Where(r => SiteID == null || r.SITE_ID == SiteID)
...
```

The SQL example is this:

```
WHERE (SITE_ID = @given OR @given IS NULL)  --return matches or all
```

Though if that value is mutable and you want the value at the time the query was built, try this instead:

```
var localSiteID = SiteID;

...
.Where(r => localSiteID == null || r.SITE_ID == SiteID)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use where  clause in one statement ..like this ..

```
  .Where(r => SiteID == null || r.SITE_ID == SiteID)
```